# Icons donot display properly in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app that fetches facebook and twitter posts. When fetched, some posts have special chars like:
❤ http://t.co/FONMMA39UR
I display it inside a UILabel. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The Label is inside a TableViewCell and I noticed that after refreshing the TableView, the icons shown.
Could anyone give the the solution?

Comment: it is based on the emoji availability on your device, if the emoticon which is displayed on web/other app is available in iOS, it will always display if valid unicode character is found in the string you are putting in UILabel

Comment: As @samfisher say that it'll always display if valid unicode character found in the string you are putting in UILabel and you said  that after refreshing the TableView, the icons shown. So my suggest is to refresh the tableview forcefully by using [yourTableView reloadData];

Comment: Yep, u right, I added method reloadData into viewDidLoad and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @samfisher say that it'll always display if valid unicode character found in the string you are putting in UILabel and you said that after refreshing the TableView, the icons shown. So my suggest is to refresh the tableview forcefully by using [yourTableView reloadData]; It'll work.